# Deserialize REST date format

Tags: c#, rest, date, deserialization

I am trying to get the timestamp in an XML file, but what it says is:

```
<diary_date>1347274789</diary_date>
```

This seams serialized to me but I didn't find any way to deserialize this format.
Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: to me it looks like it is simply converted to ticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the elapsed seconds since 1/1/1970

```
var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(1347274789); //09/10/2012 10:59:49
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: For German time, this method is 2h too late. How can I make this timestamp +2h?

Comment: @Clue Append `.ToLocalTime()`